# User Activity tracking using Image Processing

Tags: java, image-processing

I want to capture user activities happening during certain amount of time period.
I know it can be done using some native calls (JNI) but the requirement is that it 
should be done using Image Processing only. 
The tasks include,
1. Getting a screenshot of screen after every 15 seconds.
2. Find out which is currently active window and which are not using Image processing (Java).
3. Get the title of active window.

I am able to get the screenshots periodically and getting title of active 
window can be achieved using JavaOCR.
But I am not sure how to proceed with the second task. Please let me know
if there's anyone who has done similar type of work.
Please suggest what should be my approach and do post some Image Processing libraries that I can use.
Thanks.